# 17" screen panel and 2 channel 8 bit 40 pins LVDS connector on motherboard

Tags: lvds

I was looking for 17" screen panel for my motherboard. And after tones of datasheets I couldn't find any that may fit my 2ch 8bit 40pin LVDS connector. Most panels have 2ch 6bit 30/40pin or I found some 2ch 8bit but only 30pin. And can't really figure out how to connect my LVDS output to any of them panels as if I try to do it with 2ch 6bit panel then 2 pairs od Odd/Even will be missing connection from my motherboard and when I try to do it with 2ch 8bit 30pin panel then there is no input for EEID data and Colck. Is there any way to connect it, like cross cabels or just miss few pins? Are EEID data and Clock obligatory?

I attach images of LVDS input/output pin description from my motherboard and 2 panels.

[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM4Bj.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

The LVDS output on your motherboard is used for driving **LCD panel modules** *(e.g. notebook monitors)* instead of LCD panels. And an LCD panel module consists of a backlight driver unit *(e.g. ballast for CFL-lit panels or constant current source for LED-lit ones)* and LCD panel. FPD_19V on your motherboard LVDS output is for backlight module.

It seems that the 3rd image is a portion from an LCD panel, not a module. If you scan the datasheet carefully, you'll see that there's a separate connector *(probably placed on one of the corners)* for panel's backlight.

> Most panels have 2ch 6bit 30/40pin ...

There's a misconception here. Most 6-bit panels are capable of simulating 8-bit by FRC (Frame Rate Control). Check first if the panel supports **6-bit + HiFRC** or **6-bit + FRC**. So there will be no problems with driving that panel from a 8-bit LVDS channel.

> if I try to do it with 2ch 6bit panel then 2 pairs of Odd/Even will be missing connection from my motherboard

No it won't. An LVDS channel for LCD panels consists of 4 data pairs and 1 clock pair. If you check all the 3 images then you'll see that there are 4 data pairs ({R0+, R0-} to {R3+, R3-}) and 1 clock pair ({CLK+, CLK-}) for EVEN and ODD channels.

> and when I try to do it with 2ch 8bit 30pin panel then there is no input for EEDID data and Colck.

EEDID (E-EDID: Enhanced Extended Display Id. Data) is an array of data fields *(e.g. supported resolutions, brand/model info etc)* about the "panel modules" or "monitors" and it's hold by a special device (memory or MCU) of the "module". So it's meaningless for single panels.

> Are EEDID data and Clock obligatory?

For example, pin-12 and pin-15 of a VGA connector form a data line (I²C) for EDID. The computer detects if a monitor or display module is plugged in by reading EDID information over these lines. So, yes, they are obligatory. Without these lines, your motherboard cannot detect the module or monitor --or at least it cannot read any info about what is plugged in.